# How can I make an model method wait for the other at the controller scritpt? [MVC Architecture]

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

How can I make the getCityInfos() wait until the getCityName() is fulfilled at the script file controller.JS? I know that I could chain them on the model.js, is it possible also in the controller?

MODEL.JS:

```
const REVERSE_GEOCODE_API_KEY = '**********'; 
const REVERSE_GEOCODE_API_URL = 'https://geocode.maps.co/reverse?';

const WEATHER_API_KEY = '**********'; const WEATHER_API_URL = 'https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=';

export const state = {};

export const getCityInfos = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${WEATHER_API_URL}${WEATHER_API_KEY}&q=${state.latitude},${state.longitude}`
  );

  const data = await response.json();

  state.windVelocity = data.current.wind_kph;
  state.currentTemp = data.current.temp_c;

  return this;
};

export const getCityName = async () => {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (position) => {
      state.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      state.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      const response = await fetch(  `${REVERSE_GEOCODE_API_URL}lat=${state.latitude}&lon=${state.longitude}&api_key=${REVERSE_GEOCODE_API_KEY}`
      );

      const data = await response.json();

      state.cityName = data.address.town;
      state.country = data.address.country;

      return this;
    });
};
```

CONTROLLER:

```
import { getCityName, getCityInfos } from './model';

getCityName();
getCityInfos();
```

Comment: Promisify `getCurrentLocation` so you can `await` it; then `await` both `getCityName` and `getCityInfos`.